# WinRT horizontal menu autosize width of textblock so not truncated

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying (on WinRT Universal App) to have a top menu that doesn't have truncated text.
I get my items from my server and show them to my user, the problem is that I am showing items have 4 characters and some have 10 (or in-between). So some of them are truncated:
[image]
What i would like is to have a a textblock that can auto re-size it self, so that the word is not truncated, does anyone know how to do this?

here is my XAML code:

```
<GridView  ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}" 
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsRightTapEnabled="False"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
             Margin="5">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ChannelMenuHyperButtonStyle}" 
                                Text="{Binding Name}"                                    
                                Margin="10,0,10,0">
                        </TextBlock>                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"  />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
```

Style code:

```
  <Style x:Key="ChannelMenuHyperButtonStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DmBlueBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5" />
    </Style>
```

thanks you for your help!

Comment: Consider instead a `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as your `ItemsPanelTemplate`

Comment: I have the same problem with VariableSizedWrapGrid

Comment: Well damn, wasn't expecting that, guess I'll have to think about it after lunch.

Comment: Ya know, looking at this thing, why not just go with a horizontal ItemsControl with a button item template?

Comment: ill try that tomorrow at work, thx!

Comment: @Chris W. Just changing the WrapGrid into a VariablesizedWrapGrid won't have any effect, to use a VariablesizedWrapGrid you need to inherit from a GridView and override PrepareContainerForItemOverride. See this nice tutorial. http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html Doing all this for this use case is very overkill though as the OP only needs one row of items and calculating the width of textblocks can be tricky.

Comment: @oXeNoN Why on earth would you have to do all that? At most an ItemsControl would do it fine.

Comment: That is how the VariableSizedWrapGrid works, I am not suggesting it is the solution for this problem I only wanted to explain why VariableSizedWrapGrid won't work if you only change the ItemsPanel. I posted a solution below that I think is ideal (and doesn't involve any ItemsControl or VariableSizedWrapGrid)

Answer (score 0):

As you only need one row of items I would suggest to use a **VirtualizingStackPanel** as the **ItemsPanel** (Instead of a WrapGrid). Don't forget to set it's orientation to horizontal.

A Stackpanel would also work but it might become heavy in memory if you have a very high amount of categories.

Why? Because GridViews and Listviews use a WrapGrid as the default ItemsPanel, all items in an WrapGrid will have the same size (the size of the first one will be applied to all of them). They have this limitation because they are virtualized panels that can automatically layout their items in multiple rows/colums.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the Issue is that you have both margin and padding applied. For Titles that have more than 6 Char's the overlapping padding/margin is "truncating" your data.

Consider removing the Padding value from the horizontal lines in the Style "ChannelMenuHyperButtonStyle".

```
<Style x:Key="ChannelMenuHyperButtonStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DmBlueBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,5,0,5" />
</Style>
```

Remember Margin is making space from the outside of the bounds, padding is making space from inside the bounds.

Comment: His Padding/Margin is only an issue since he's using a fixed size item panel set by the first item in the collection. Which is why everything with 5 chars or less (like "Music" or "Funny") display fine, but anything past 5 chars gets clipped.